# How can I write Python selenium test for PrimeFaces?

Tags: python, selenium, primefaces

I am trying to write a Selenium test but the issue is I have learned that the page is generated with PrimeFaces, thus the element IDs randomly change from time to time. Not using IDs is not very reliable. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Can't you assign IDs to the JSF components in xhtml source?

Comment: So that typically means the developer was not assigning proper id's to all elements on the page if you are seeing things like "jidt_47" etc.  In all of our PrimeFaces apps we assign real id's where we can so they are not autogenerated like you are seeing.  Is there any way you can get the developers to update the app to assign proper id's?

Comment: I do not have access to the code. I may try to talk with the developers but I doubt that I can get them to change IDs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not having meaningful stable IDs is not a problem, as there are always alternative ways to locate elements on a page. Just to name a few options:

- partial id matches with XPath or CSS, e.g.:

  ```
   # contains
   driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span[id*=customer]")
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@id, 'customer')]")

   # starts with
   driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span[id^=customer]")
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[starts-with(@id, 'customer')]")

   # ends with
   driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span[id$=customer]")
  ```
- classes which refer/tell some valuable information about the data types ("data-oriented locators"):

  ```
   driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".price")
   driver.find_element_by_class_name("price")
  ```
- going sideways from a label:

  ```
   # <label>Price</label><span id="65123safg12">10.00</span>
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[.='Price']/following-sibling::span")
  ```
- links by link text or partial link text:

  ```
   driver.find_element_by_link_text("Information")
   driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("more")
  ```

And, you can, of course, get creative and combine them. There are more:

- [Locating Elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

There is also this relevant thread which goes over best practices when choosing a method to locate an element on a page:

- [What makes a good selenium locator?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/27978/5574)

Comment: Thank you, I was only using basic selectors llike find_element_by_id, by_xpath, by_css, by_text etc. and didn't know about variances and combinations and I have used // for the first time. I will look up what it is used for.